# Creating task or a view for search results

Tags: joomla

I'm making a search for joomla, after clicking search button I am getting this url:

```
index.php?searchword=aa&task=search
```

How can I create a view or task for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the basic joomla search component you will find the views in

`/components/com_search/views/search/tmpl`

If you edit the view then its advisable to use template overrides, to ensure you will not lose your views on upgrade : http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

**addition :**

If you are building a component and you want a task to execute like that, then use this in your `YourComponentName.php`.

```
$controller   = JController::getInstance('FrontendSuite');
$controller->execute(JRequest::getVar('task'));
$controller->redirect();
```

And add the task as a function in your `controller.php`. You will get something like this :

```
function search(){
    $searchword = JRequest::getVar('searchword');
    //Do your magic
}
```

As Valentin pointed out just below, you will need to add `option=com_yoursearchcomponent` to your URL for Joomla to call your component.

Adding Views to your component is explained quite well in the link Valentin posted below, http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_a_view_to_the_site_part

Hope this helps,

Good luck

Comment: no no no. I'm creating custom search component. I need to create view or task for this index.php?searchword=aa&task=search URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL will be like:

> index.php?option=com_yoursearchcomponent&task=search&keyword=xxx

So you need to create a component. Have a look at the **[Developing a Model-View-Controller Component.](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Introduction)**

Then you will have in your controller or subcontroller the task search which will call the view search, where you will have the appropiate template for the view.